# ios - Compare the value of objects in array and put in same section

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, object

im currently having issue with the logical of array and object, hope everyone can cure my dumbness, thanks!

Here's what im having:

```
NSArray data = @[@[@"year",@"name"],
                 @[@"2015",@"A"],
                 @[@"2014",@"B"],....
                ];

//have 100 small array, year can be similar
```

So i wanna ask how can i loop through them, compare the year of the object with the next object, then if the year is same, put it into a NSDictionary similar to the data array but with the key = the year:

```
 NSDictionary dict = @[@"year":@[@"year",@"name"],
                       @"2015":@[@[@"2015",@"A"],@[@"2015",@"C"]],
                       @"2014":@[@"2014",@"B"],
                       @"2013":@[@"2013",@"D"],...
                      ];
```

What i tried using predicate give me what i want...but i not sure how to do it with like many different kind of year (i think this is wrong, not sure)

```
NSString *searchTerm = @"2015";
//predicate1 is compare all the value with 2015, same then product array of them, predicate2 is product array of all array that dont have 2015 inside
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF == %@", searchTerm];
NSArray *filtered1 = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate1];
NSLog(@"%@", filtered1); 

NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF != %@", searchTerm];
NSArray *filtered2 = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate2];
NSLog(@"%@", filtered2);
```

This give me 2 array that have same year in small array inside

```
//output of 2 array:
filtered1 = @[@[@"2015",@"diff name"],
              @[@"2015",@"A"],..
              ];
filtered2 = @[@[@"other year",@"diff name"],
              @[@"2014",@"B"],...
              ];
```

What i think is that get the year of first small array, then compare with the year of the rest 99 small array, product the array of that first year, get the other small array, then do it again...but not sure how to implements it

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop and check against the previous record, I didnt 100% understand what you want to do when you have a successful find but this should work

```
NSString *prevData;
NSMutableArray *newData=[NSMutableArray array];
//check the last one
for (int i=0;i< data.count;i++)
{
     NSArray currentData= [data objectAtIndex:i];
     if(i!=0  && ([currentData objectAtIndex:0] isEqualTo:[prevData objectAtIndex:0])) 
     {
         //add the data to newData
         [newData addObject:currentData];
     }
     prevData=currentData


}
```

Comment: thankyou, i have clear out the result that i wanted...is that possible of making?

Comment: sorry tien, i didnt get what you mean